# How to store data into a many-to-many relationship in CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

So i'm developing a workout tracker application and i have one entity which has all the exercises and another which will have saved workouts. I have setup a many-to-many relationship between the two as a workout can have many exercises and an exercise could have many workouts. I've subclassed my entities and i've been given these two variables...

```
// Workout Entity...
@NSManaged public var exercises: NSSet?

// Exercises Entity...
@NSManaged public var workouts: NSSet?
```

And i'm confused on how to write data to them. I have setup a tableview with all the exercises and when the user selects one it displays a checkmark. But i also want it to be saved to the relationships. So that when i query the data later on for a workout for example i want it to show me all the associated exercises on that workout. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which is your target iOS version?

Comment: IoS 10, most recent. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Should be quite easy.
I guess you have a function which returns all selectes Workouts, i called it `selectedExercises()` you just need to connect each exercise property with the workout property, and of course connect the workout property with each exercise
Something like that should do it for you:

```
let context = ...// your context

guard let workout = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Workout", into: context) as? Workout else {
    fatalError()
}

let exercises = selectedExercises() //func returning an NSSet
let workoutsSet = NSSet(object: workout)

for exercise in exercises {
    guard let exercise = exercise as? Exercise else { fatalError() }
    exercise.workouts = workoutsSet
}

workout.exercises = exercises

do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    fatalError()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already created actual instances of your workout/exercise entities, Xcode generates methods to add and remove one or multiple related objects for you:

```
// MARK: Generated accessors for exercises
extension WorkoutEntity {

    @objc(addExercisesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToExercises(_ value: ManagedEmotionCategory)

    @objc(removeExercisesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromExercises(_ value: ManagedEmotionCategory)

    @objc(addExercises:)
    @NSManaged public func addToExercises(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeExercises:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromExercises(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

You can use them on you existing instances:

```
workoutInstance.addToExercises(exerciseInstance)
```

The inverse relationship is set by Core Data automatically, so:

```
exerciseInstance.workouts.contains(workoutInstance)
```

is now `true`.